# Confusion regarding reflexive pronoun

Tags: grammar, pronouns

A native English speaker today wrote: "An advertisement is live now for an associate-ship with myself and Richard". Is using the reflexive pronoun *myself* correct in this sentence? I thought it should be *me*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In traditional grammar, that is an error.  As you say, it should be "me", in fact, "Richard and me" would be better.

However it is a common 'error' that native speakers make. Sometimes using "myself" can seem sophisticated. Some people get very angry about this.
So you should properly consider using "myself" to be bad English, and not a grammatical error like "An advertisement am live now..."

As an example of bad English, learners should avoid this usage, but understand that others, including native speakers will use "myself" like this.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!